# Can't render DataTable using Vue and PrimeVue from CDN

Tags: vue.js, datatable, render, cdn, primevue

I'm using PrimeVue with the CDN option. In the tutorial, it says "Include the component to use with a script tag". But some components work without importing, just registering them as components is enough, such as buttons, messages, input texts, etc, but with others, such as DataTable, only works importing first. Also, it would be helpful if there were a list of all the components in tutorial for CDN option to import, it only shows how to import the Calendar.

The HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PrimeVue Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/core/core.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p-datatable :value="items">
            <p-column field="id" header="Id"></p-column>
            <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>            
        </p-datatable>
        <p-button label="Submit"></p-button>
        <p-inputtext type="text" />
        <p-message>Message</p-message>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The app.js script:

```
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const App = {
    setup() {
        const items = ref([{ id: 1, name: 'Item 1'}])
        return { items }
    },
    components: {
        "p-button": primevue.button,
        "p-inputtext": primevue.inputtext,
        "p-message": primevue.message,       
        "p-column": primevue.column,
        "p-datatable": primevue.datatable
    }
}
createApp(App).use(primevue.config.default).mount("#app")
```

The others components work, but the DataTable gives the warning message on console:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <PDatatable value= ...
```

So, when the DataTable components are imported, the problem is fixed:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/datatable/datatable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/column/column.min.js"></script>
```

Although the other components didn't need to be imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CDN, you have to load components individually (see [docs](https://primevue.org/cdn/#component)), so for datatable and column, you need to add:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/datatable/datatable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/column/column.min.js"></script>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const App = {
  setup() {
    const products = ref([])
    return {
      products
    }
  },
  components: {
    "p-column": primevue.column,
    "p-datatable": primevue.datatable
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
  .use(primevue.config.default)
  .mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/core/core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/datatable/datatable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/column/column.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="app">
  <p-datatable :value="products">
    <p-column field="code" header="Code"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="category" header="Category"></p-column>
    <p-column field="quantity" header="Quantity"></p-column>
  </p-datatable>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

---

There are a few components that seem to be included in core, so you don't have to import them individually:

- BaseComponent
- Badge
  ​- BaseIcon
  ​- Button
- Checkbox
- Dialog
- Dropdown
- InputNumber
- InputText
- Menu
- Message
- Paginator
- Portal
- ProgressBar
- RadioButton
- TieredMenu
- Tree
- VirtualScroller

Comment: It solves the issue, I edited the post so I could explain better the situation. Other components work without loading them, just registering them. The only one so far that needs to be loaded is the DataTable. I've tried to report this to PrimeVue on Github, but its too complicated.

Comment: Hmm, the `primvevue` object from `core` has stubs for most components (like datatable and column), but some seem to be fully included, my guess is that those are used too frequently to leave them out (inputs, dialogs,  etc.). I have added the list to the answer. All others I think you have to import individually.